# Последовательность не повторяющихся числе в заданном диапазоне

Tags: html, javascript, массивы

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for ( var list = [], i = 0; i < 4; ) {
    list[ i ] = ++i;
        }
    list.sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - .5;
    });
    $('.play').click(function(event) {
        $('.start').css('display', 'none');
        $('.question#'+list.shift()).addClass('active');
        var num = $('.active').attr('id');
        $('.question.active').append('<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay" src=" '+num+'.mp3 "></audio>')
        console.log(num);
        console.log(list);
        console.log(list.shift());
    });
    $('.btn').click(function(event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('yes')) {
            $("#player")[0].pause();
            $(this).parent().css('display', 'none').removeClass('active');
            $('.question#'+list.shift()).addClass('active');
            var num = $('.active').attr('id');
            $('.question.active').append('<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay" src=" '+num+'.mp3 "></audio>')
        }else{
            $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
        }
        console.log(num);
        console.log(list);
        console.log(list.shift());
    });
});
```

Не могу понять, где ошибка. Скрипт берет случайное число из массива. подставляет его в айдишник и включает блок с этим айди. Но вот проблема в том, что на кнопку можно нажать всего 2 раза, потом выдает undefined. Помогите разобратсья

Comment: Ну так [shift](http://javascript.ru/Array/shift) удаляет элементы из `list`. Поэтому через несколько нажатий там ничего не останется. Если вам необходимо циклически сдвигать `.active`, то добавляйте элемент полученный через `shift` в конец массива.

Comment: И для таких вопросов для кода лучше использовать [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). По вашему описанию не понятно где "потом выдает undefined". А на jsfiddle можно было бы поковыряться и увидеть все самому. К тому же там же можно было бы указать примерную структуру html

Comment: Прошу прощения.
https://jsfiddle.net/37oL2oe4/
весь вопрос в том, что по логике вещей.. массив состоит из 4 элементов и по 1 должно убираться, но происходит 3-1-undefined

Comment: Хе-хе, а что должно делаться? У вас при нажатии на кнопку происходит два shift\`a: первый в коде (он вроде нужен), а второй - отладочный. Поэтому если в массиве у нас `[3, 2, 1, 0]`, то после shift\`a в функции у нас станет `[2, 1, 0]`, а после вывода отладочной инфы останется `[1, 0]`. Т.е. как раз и получается то, что вы говорите

Comment: Не совсем понимаю ) как исправить можно, подскажете?

Comment: Закомментируйте `console.log(list.shift());` - у вас уже не будут удаляться лишний раз элементы. Если так надо знать что находится в `list`, так и выводите только его (ну либо `list[0]`, что не совсем правильно)

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую